# How to prove $\sqrt{x + y} \le \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, radicals

How do I prove $\sqrt{x + y} \le \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$? for $x, y$ positive?

This should be easy, but I'm not seeing how.  A hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For positive $x, y$, we have:

$$\sqrt{x + y} \leq \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \iff \left(\sqrt{x + y}\right)^2 \leq \left(\sqrt x + \sqrt y\right)^2 \iff \color{blue}{\bf x + y \leq x + y + 2\sqrt{xy}}$$

What can you conclude about the leftmost "inequality", given its equivalence to the $\color{blue}{\bf rightmost\;inequality}$?

Comment: can you extend this for more variables?

Answer (score 12):

**Hint:** For positive numbers $a$ and $b$,
$$a\leq b\iff a^2\leq b^2.$$

Answer (score 4):

Draw a right triangle with the two sides making the $90^\circ$ angle of length $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{y}$. Then, by the Pytagorean Theorem, the Hypotenuse is $\sqrt{x+y}$.

Since the sum of two edges exceeds the third edge you get

$$\sqrt{x+y} < \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y} \,.$$

Comment: Can the downvoter explain what is wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 3):

Putting everything together, suppose $x,y>0$. Then $0\le2\sqrt{xy}$. Hence:
$$ 
\sqrt{x+y} = \sqrt{x+0+y}
\le \sqrt{x+2\sqrt{xy}+y} 
= \sqrt{(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^2} 
= \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y} 
$$
as desired. Note that this relied on the fact that $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is monotonically increasing.