# Why is $\sqrt x \times \sqrt y = \sqrt {xy}$

Tags: radicals

Sorry I do not know latex. Why is $\sqrt x \times \sqrt y = \sqrt {xy}$? It also applies for division, but why not addition and subtraction? i.e., why is $\sqrt x + \sqrt y$ not equal to $\sqrt {x+y}$? 
Thank you for editing and answering.

Comment: It is indeed not true that $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{x+y}$ in general, but it is true that [$\sqrt{x+y}\leq \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408177/proving-sqrtx-y-le-sqrtx-sqrty) for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^+$, which is easy to prove.

Comment: $\sqrt x + \sqrt y\neq \sqrt{x+y}$ for the same reason as $(x+y)^2\neq x^2+y^2$.

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. If any of them is what you need, you should **accept** it by clicking the grey tick mark below the question score. Otherwise, explain what is still missing in the answers!

Answer (score 2):

You were told in the comments where to find an answer to your first question. Now, why is it *not* true that $\sqrt{x+y}=\sqrt x+\sqrt y$? Because, for instance, $\sqrt1+\sqrt1=2$, whereas $\sqrt{1+1}=\sqrt2<2$.

Answer (score 1):

remember what $^2$ is:

$$u^2=u\cdot u\\\text{so: }\left(\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{b}\right)^2=\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{b}\cdot\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{b}\cdot\sqrt{b}=a\cdot b=\sqrt{ab}^2\implies\sqrt x \cdot\sqrt y = \sqrt {xy}\\\text{and you can do: }\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\right)^2=\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\right)\cdot\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\right)=\sqrt{a}^2+2\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{b}^2{=a+2\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{b}+b}=\sqrt{a+2\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{b}+b}^2\ne\sqrt{a+b}^2\implies\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\ne\sqrt{a+b}$$