# Is square root sublinear?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, lipschitz-functions

I want to prove that $\sqrt x $ is sublinear, but i don't know how to do it, precisely i'm having difficulties stating that $\sqrt x $ is sublinear in $[0, 1]$
$$\\ f(x)\ is\ sublinear\ \iff\ \exists\ a,b \in\ \mathbb R\ \mid\ |f(x)| \le a|x| + b  $$

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/408177/42969

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove $\sqrt{x + y} \le \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408177/how-to-prove-sqrtx-y-le-sqrtx-sqrty)

Comment: No, i added the definition

Comment: Forgive me if I'm mistaken, but according to your definition, can't you just let a=100000, and b=1 to create a line that is always above $|{\sqrt{x}}|$ in your given range?

Comment: This is not a proof, even with $a=10^{100}$. @yolo

Comment: @nicomezi I didn't bother with rigour to that excess as I assumed that it was a misnomer on the OP's wording, since it seemed too obvious,

Answer (score 0):

Your $x$ is non-negative. We need $a$ and $b$ such that

$$ \forall x \ge 0 \quad 0\le\sqrt x \le ax +b.$$

Raise to the power $2$:
$$0 \le a^2 x^2 + (2 a b - 1) x + b^2$$

Take for simplicity $a=1$:
$$0 \le x^2 + (2 b - 1) x + b^2,$$
and that for $x\ge0$. It is sufficient to take $2b-1\ge0$.

Comment: But then if i use a b>0 the negative x straight line will not be under the graph of $\sqrt x$ like here:
https://www.google.com/search?q=square+root+of+x+is+not+lipschitz&rlz=1C1ONGR_itIT974IT974&sxsrf=APq-WBuvlxWBAtnvWD2JYeO7FGYuRBXHTQ:1649253422991&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjT16_jy__2AhWui_0HHSmWA8cQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1242&bih=568&dpr=1.1#imgrc=gStxtpyljJLhqM

Comment: $\sqrt x$ is not defined for $x<0$. The first graph is $\sqrt{|x|}$ @GiuseppeFontanella

Comment: i'm sorry i intended that to be sublinear the function has to have its own graph contained between two straight line with opposite angular coefficients like in the link i posted in the previous comment

Comment: @Iruo Perhaps you should use this condition:

$\forall x_1,x_2, \exists K \mid \left | f(x_{1})-f(x_{2}) \right |\leq K\left | x_{1}-x_{2} \right |$

Comment: @Iruo then you need to ask for Lipschitz continuity, not sublinearity; square root is not Lipschitz continuous on $[0,\infty)$.